# What is the best practice to handle fulfillment using PHP & google/cloud-dialogflow library

Tags: php, laravel, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm able to receive requests on Dialogflow Intent fulfillment event on my server [Laravel Framework - PHP]

However, I am unable to handle the webhook request using the official Google Dialogflow Library for PHP.

I am not sure if I understand it right, but according to [google dialogflow docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview), when an intent is fulfilled, I should use the [WebhookRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookrequest) class to receive the request and [WebhookRespone](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse) class to prepare my response (add context, message text, etc) and send it back to the server.

My problem is, I do not know how to initialise the WebhookRequest, and I don't know how to render the WebhookRespone and convert it to JSON.

Expected code regarding WebhookRequest:

```
$params = $request->all();//All Json From webhook request in one array.
$webhookRequest = new WebhookRequest($params);
$sessionName = $webhookRequest->getSession();
$queryResult = $webhookRequest->getQueryResult();
```

Expected code regarding WebhookResponse

```
$webhookResponse = new WebhookResponse();
$webhookResponse->setFulfillmentText("Hello World");
return response()->json($webhookResponse->toJson());//Laravel Way to send back response
```

I am aware of the [eristemena/dialogflow-fulfillment-webhook-php](https://github.com/eristemena/dialogflow-fulfillment-webhook-php#get-request-info) library, but it is not an official Google API, and I'm not sure if it is the best practice because the library is not maintained by Google.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "expected code"? Is that code you wrote that didn't work? Did it give an error, or an unexpected result?